# Is there a R function to match matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, match

my data is like this

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,2,5,6,3,6,9),nrow = 3)
rownames(x) <- c('a','b','c')
colnames(x) <- c('a','b','c')
```

[image]

I also have

```
y <- matrix(c('a','b','a','a','a','c'),ncol = 2)
```

[image]

I want to do a match like

[image]

please not use the 'for' loop because the data is big (like million)

Is there any package to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `y` matrix as an index to subset values from `x` and add as a new column.

```
cbind(y, x[y])

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "a"  "1" 
#[2,] "b"  "a"  "2" 
#[3,] "a"  "c"  "3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,this mothd is also work well in million obs.

Comment: what's more, I want to know how is the x[y] working? If x have 3 columns,but I just want 2 columns to do the matching.what should i do?@Ronak Shah

Comment: `x` is the matrix from where we get the data. So `x` can be of any column it does not matter as far as those column and rownames are present in `y`.